# Why does setting a base class equal to a derived type only work within scope of where it is set?

Tags: c#, polymorphism, covariance

I found it difficult to come up with a descriptive enough title for this scenario so I'll let the code do most of the talking.

Consider covariance where you can substitute a derived type for a base class.

```
class Base
{

}

class Derived : Base
{

}
```

Passing in `typeof(Base)` to this method and setting that variable to the derived type is possible.

```
private void TryChangeType(Base instance)
{
  var d = new Derived();
  instance = d;
  Console.WriteLine(instance.GetType().ToString());
}
```

However, when checking the type from the caller of the above function, the instance will still be of type `Base`

```
private void CallChangeType()
{
  var b = new Base();
  TryChangeType(b);
  Console.WriteLine(b.GetType().ToString());
}
```

I would assume since objects are inherently reference by nature that the caller variable would now be of type `Derived`. The only way to get the caller to be type `Derived` is to pass a reference object by `ref` like so

```
private void CallChangeTypeByReference()
{
  var b = new Base();
  TryChangeTypeByReference(ref b);
  Console.WriteLine(b.GetType().ToString());
}  
private void TryChangeTypeByReference(ref Base instance)
{
  var d = new Derived();
  instance = d;
}
```

Further more, I feel like it's common knowledge that passing in an object to a method, editing props, and passing that object down the stack will keep the changes made down the stack. This makes sense as the object is a reference object.

### What causes an object to permanently change type down the stack, only if it's passed in by reference?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have a great many confused and false beliefs. Let's fix that.

> Consider covariance where you can substitute a derived type for a base class.

**That is not covariance**.  That is **assignment compatibility**.  An Apple is *assignment compatible* with a variable of type Fruit because you can assign an Apple to such a variable. Again, **that is not covariance**.  Covariance is the fact that a *transformation* on a type *preserves* the assignment compatibility relationship.  A *sequence of apples* can be used somewhere that a *sequence of fruit* is needed *because apples are a kind of fruit*.  **That is covariance**.  The mapping "apple --> sequence of apples, fruit --> sequence of fruit" is a *covariant mapping*.

Moving on.

> Passing in `typeof(Base)` to this method and setting that variable to the derived type is possible.

You are confusing types with instances.  You do not pass `typeof(Base)` to this method; you pass a reference to `Base` to this instance.  `typeof(Base)` is of type `System.Type`.

As you correctly note, **formal parameters are variables**.  A formal parameter is a new variable, and it is initialized to the *actual parameter* aka *argument*.

> However, when checking the type from the caller of the above function, the instance will still be of type Base

Correct.  The **argument** is of type `Base`.  You copy that to a *variable*, and then you *reassign* the variable.  This is no different than saying:

```
Base x = new Base();
Base y = x;
y = new Derived();
```

And now `x` is still `Base` and `y` is `Derived`.  You assigned the same variable twice; the second assignment wins.  This is no different than if you said `a = 1; b = a; b = 2;` -- you would not expect `a` to be `2` afterwards just because you said `b = a` in the past.

> I would assume since objects are inherently reference by nature that the caller variable would now be of type Derived.

That assumption is wrong.  Again, **you have made two assignments to the same variable**, and you have **two variables**, one in the caller, and one in the callee.  **Variables contain values; references to objects are values**.

> The only way to get the caller to be type Derived is to pass a reference object by ref like so

Now we're getting to the crux of the problem.

The correct way to think about this is that **ref makes an alias to a variable**.  A normal formal parameter is *a new variable*.  A `ref` formal parameter *makes the variable in the formal parameter an alias to the variable at the call site*.  So now you have *one variable* but it has *two names*, because the name of the formal parameter is an *alias* for the variable at the call.  This is the same as:

```
Base x = new Base();
ref Base y = ref x; // x and y are now two names for the same variable
y = new Derived(); // this assigns both x and y because there is only one variable, with two names
```

> Further more, I feel like it's common knowledge that passing in an object to a method, editing props, and passing that object down the stack will keep the changes made down the stack. This makes sense as the object is a reference object.

Correct.

The mistake you are making here is very common.  It was a bad idea for the C# design team to name the variable aliasing feature "ref" because this causes confusion.  A reference to a **variable** makes an **alias**; it gives another name to a variable.  A reference to an **object** is a token that represents a specific object with a specific identity.  When you mix the two it gets confusing.

The normal thing to do is to *not* pass variables by `ref` particularly if they contain references.

> What causes an object to permanently change type down the stack, only if it's passed in by reference?

Now we have the most fundamental confusion.  **You have confused objects with variables**.  An object **never** changes its type, ever!  An apple is an object, and an apple is now and forever an apple. An apple *never* becomes any other kind of fruit.

Stop thinking that variables are objects, right now. Your life will get so much better.  Internalize these rules:

- variables are storage locations that store values
- references to objects are values
- objects have a type that never changes
- `ref` gives a new name to an existing variable
- assigning to a variable changes its value

Now if we ask your question again using correct terminology, the confusion disappears immediately:

> What causes the value of a variable to change its type down the stack, only if it's passed in by `ref`?

The answer is now very clear:

- A variable passed by `ref` is an alias to another variable, so changing the value of the parameter is the same as changing the value of the variable at the call site
- Assigning an object reference to a variable changes the value of that variable
- An object has a particular type

If we don't pass by ref but instead pass normally:

- A value passed normally is copied to a new variable, the formal parameter
- We now have two variables with no connection; changing one of them does not change the other.

If that's still not clear, start drawing boxes, circles and arrows on a whiteboard, where objects are circles, variables are boxes, and object references are arrows from variables to objects.  Making an alias via `ref` gives a new name to an existing circle; calling without `ref` makes a second circle and copies the arrow. It'll all make sense then.

Answer (score 1):

We know that class are reference types, so in general when we are passing a type, we are passing a reference but there's a difference between passing just `b` and `ref b`, which can be understood as:

1. In first case 1 it is passing **reference by value**, which means creating a separate pointer internally to the memory location, now when base class object is assigned to the derived class object, it starts pointing to another object in the memory and when that method returns, only the original pointer remains, which provides the same instance as Base class, when the new pointer created is off for garbage collection
2. However when object is passed as **ref**, this is passing **reference to a reference** in memory, which is like pointer to a pointer, like double pointer in C or C++, which when changes actually changes the original memory allocation and thus you see the difference

For first one to show the same result value has to be returned from the method and old object shall start pointing to the new derived object

Following is the modification to your program to get expected result in case 1:

```
private Base TryChangeType(Base instance)
{
    var d = new Derived();
    instance = d;

    Console.WriteLine(instance.GetType().ToString());

    return instance;
}

private void CallChangeType()
{
    var b = new Base();
    b = TryChangeType(b);
    Console.WriteLine(b.GetType().ToString());
}
```

Following is the pictorial reference of both the cases:

[image]

Comment: Explaining references as pointers assumes that the reader already knows how pointer semantics work, but readers who already know that already know how references work. This seems like a "it's clear only if I already know it" explanation.

Comment: Certainly assumption is at play, because that's the simplest way in my view to see, how memory allocation works internally. Added the pictorial reference to  ensure more clarity

Answer (score 1):

This is not an issue with inheritance and polymorphism, what you're seeing is the difference between pass-by-value and pass-by-reference.

```
private void TryChangeType(Base instance)
```

The preceding method's instance parameter will be a **copy** of the caller's Base reference. You can change the object that is referenced and those changes will be visible to the caller because both the caller the callee both reference the same object. But, **any changes to the reference itself (such as pointing it to a new object) will not affect the caller's reference**. This is why it works as expected when you pass by reference.

Answer (score 1):

When you call TryChangeType() you are passing a copy of the *reference* to "b" into "instance". Any changes to *members* of "instance" are made in the same memory space still referenced by "b" in your calling method.  However, the command "instance = d" *reassigns the value of the memory* addressed by "instance". "b" and "instance no longer point to the same memory.  When you return to CallChangeType, "b" still references the original space and hence Type.
TryChangeTypeByReference passes the a reference to where "b"'s pointer value is actually stored.  Reassigning "instance" now changes the address that "b" is actually pointing to.

Answer (score 0):

When you do not pass by reference, a copy of the base class object is passed inside the function, and this copy is changed inside the TryChangeType function. When you print the type of the instance of the base class it is still the of the type "Base" because the copy of the instance was changed to "Derived" class.

When you pass by referece, the address of the instance i.e. the instace itself will be passed to the function. So any changes made to the instance inside the function is permanent.

Comment: It is always passing reference, it's never a copy as in value types, its always reference to the original allocation, difference is explicit reference to actual memory allocation or reference to a reference like double pointer